# Check an expression with a regex

Tags: java, regex, expression

I have this method, which I use to create an array of a conditional expression.

```
private void convertToList() {
    String regex = "[-]?[0-9]+([eE][-]?[0-9]+)?|([-+/*\\\\^])|([()])|(!)|(>=)|(<=)|(<)|(>)|(&&)|(==)|(!=)|([|][|])|(\\[)|(\\])|(and)|(or)|(not)|(true)|(false)|([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)";
    Matcher m3 = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this.stringExp);
    this.arrayExp = new ArrayList<String>(this.stringExp.length());
    while (m3.find()) {
        arrayExp.add(m3.group());
    }
}
```

The expression can contain words, numbers and operators (which you can see in the regex).

Now I want to check if the expression is valid before tokenizing. I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
private static void checkString(String s){
    String regex = "[-]?[0-9]+([eE][-]?[0-9]+)?|([-+/*\\\\^])|([()])|(!)|(>=)|(<=)|(<)|(>)|(&&)|(==)|(!=)|([|][|])|(\\[)|(\\])|(and)|(or)|(not)|(true)|(false)|([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)";
    Matcher m3 = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
    if (m3.matches()){
        System.out.println("OK");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not ok");
    }
}
```

Examples of valid strings:

```
"a + b < 5"
"a <= b && c > 1 || a == 4"
```

Anyway to do that?

Comment: You are probably having problems with spaces. In your example strings are spaces, but they don't match in the regex.

Comment: Since you're trying to check expressions you might have better luck using a parser instead of Regular Expressions to validate.  Janino is one you can try: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home but it might be overkill

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux : Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably having problems with spaces. In your example strings are spaces, but they don't match in the regex.